# Instances of older workflow version when deploying newer one

Tags: 2010, workflow, deployment

The question's about Sharepoint 2010.

Let's consider a following scenario: there are instances of a workflow X in progress at the server (for example, waiting for user's interaction). Then, deployment of a newer version of the same workflow takes place, overwriting the existing one.

May it happen that the deployment of newer version interfere with already running instances of OLDER version of workflow X?

1. Will the old instances behave as they were defined?
2. Or will they behave as it was defined in the newer version of workflow X (if for example user added or deleted some actions)
3. Or will they stop / crash etc.?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old Instances of workflow are just old versions (copies of the workflow of a specific version, if you will). They will not reflect the changes you made to the current or updated workflow. They will run normally without crashing, considering that they do not have any flaws. They will run until they are told to stop or stop according to the workflow. Updating a workflow will not cause any harm to the old instances running.

Comment: Workflows are stored in the database after binary serialization. If the updated workflow points to the same assembly and if it has changes to the tasks, add/delete of new/existing task or any changes to the assembly may cause problems with the de-serialization of the binary data once workflow engine wakes up.